# Count range by condition that involves 2 other ranges

Tags: google-sheets-formula

### Background

- In **`sheet A`**: Range `A5:A24` *[no headers]* contains a list of classes (i.e. math, English, etc.)
- In **`sheet B`**: Range `H5:O` *[no headers]* contains a table of classes events:

  - `H5:H` is the class name (can be from the list in **`sheet A`** or not)
  - `I5:I` is the teacher's name
  - `J5:J` is the date
  - `K5:O` is the attending students' names (can be anything between 1 and 5 names for any class).

### Goal

In **`sheet A`**, range `B5:B24` - I want to have a total count of students for each class in range `A5:A24`.

Meaning: for each row of range `H5:O` in **`sheet B`** - count string values in columns `K` to `O` if cell column `H` is found in range `A5:A24` in **`sheet A`**. Then, sum it up per each row in this last range.

*This can theoretically be between 0 to infinity (depending on the occurrences of a class and the number of attending students.*

- For each row in **`sheet B`** - students should be counted (even if it's the same students like in other occurences).

### Example Spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T7_zPxbGmyLSSWQ3ur443EY9zjbNhy4EAJyZtXsfr4o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have tried different combitations of `ARRAYFORMULA`, `COUNTIF`, `SUM` and more, but couldn't get where I wanted

Comment: Show you data and output manually so that we can make formula to get that output.

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think putting this formula in 'Sheet A'!B5:B24 will do the trick:

```
=counta(iferror(filter('Sheet B'!$K$5:$O,'Sheet B'!$H$5:$H=A5),))
```

Comment: Seems it does, thanks! Is there a way to use `ARRAYFORMULA` here that will allow use of formula in cell B5 only?

Comment: Also, is the `IFERROR `  here necessary? Can’t think of a situation an error will be returned.

Comment: I can't immediately think of a solution using `ARRAYFORMULA`, there must be one, but much more complex (probably requires several steps of transformation of your array before you can start counting). The `IFERROR` function is necessary for when there is no hit, as otherwise the `FILTER` function will return `#N/A` which will then be counted as `1` in the `COUNTA` function.